# Selenium clicking a specific button object from a list of objects with python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am grabbing a list of buttons, then I am attempting to click a specific button object, I collect all buttons (which contain details such as a name). I check the name, if I have already clicked on this button, pass, or else click this button object.

The problem I am having is that the button doesn't have an ID so I am unsure of how to dynamically identify the button to click it (from the object in the loop). It doesn't have an HREF either.

If it had an ID, I could grab the ID value and build a selenium click even such as `browser.find_element(By.ID, "button-ID").click()`.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
buttons = soup.find_all('button', {'class', 'full-width'})
for button in buttons:
    button_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(button), 'lxml')
    name_div = button_soup.find('div', {'class': 'artdeco-entity-lockup__title'})
    name = name_div.find('span', {'aria-hidden': 'true'}).text
    if name in lead_check:
        pass
    else:
        """HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO CLICK THE BUTTON OBJECT"""
        browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.full-width").click()
```

Button Object (one button from loop) example

```
<button class="full-width member-analytics-addon__cta-list-item-content member-analytics-addon-entity-list__link member-analytics-addon-entity-list__link--no-underline-hover" role="button" type="button">
<div class="member-analytics-addon-entity-list__entity artdeco-entity-lockup artdeco-entity-lockup--size-3 ember-view" id="112">
<div class="artdeco-entity-lockup__image artdeco-entity-lockup__image--type-circle ember-view" id="113" type="circle">
<div class="ivm-image-view-model">
<div class="ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex">
<!-- --> <img alt="" class="ivm-view-attr__img--centered EntityPhoto-circle-3 EntityPhoto-circle-3 lazy-image ember-view" height="48" id="114" loading="lazy" src="linktopic" width="48"/>
</div>
</div>
<!-- -->
</div>
<div class="artdeco-entity-lockup__content ember-view member-analytics-addon-entity-list__entity-content" id="115">
<div>
<div class="artdeco-entity-lockup__title ember-view member-analytics-addon-entity-list__entity-content-title" id="116">
<span dir="ltr"><span aria-hidden="true"><!-- -->John Smith<!-- --></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!-- -->View Johns’s profile<!-- --></span></span>
</div>
<div class="artdeco-entity-lockup__badge ember-view t-normal" id="117"><!-- --> <span aria-hidden="false" class="artdeco-entity-lockup__degree">
    · 3rd
  </span>
<!-- --><!-- --></div>
<div class="artdeco-entity-lockup__subtitle ember-view" id="118">
<!-- -->Loves cats<!-- -->
</div>
<!-- --> </div>
<!-- --> </div>
</div>
</button>
```

Comment: why not click on the button with `browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')` or `browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'member-analytics-addon__cta-list-item-content')` ?

Comment: because I will always hit the same button

Comment: if you instead use selenium to find all of the buttons objects and use that for the for loop you would be able to stack the dot operators to search within that element for the particular button that you want

Comment: Arr ok, I did try initially with selenium but I couldn't work it out as I had to navigate away from the page and then back to use the next button. I navigate to the page on the button click, collect data then come back to use the next button and click, collect, repeat.

Comment: could you instead store the webpage that you navigate to? then come back to that later to collect data all at once? or you could add enumerate() to your buttons element and then index into that element via `browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'full-width').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')` ?

Comment: What site are you using so that I can offer a better recommendation?

Comment: If the buttons had HREFs I could store the links but they don't and I can't think of a way to identify the link they go to. Its a local LAN app

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you are working on? I hope we will be able to uniquely locate buttons depending on other elements there

Comment: I have solved this myself, thanks for the help and unwarranted downvotes are always welcome of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by identifying a unique variable in each button, in this instance an IMG URL then dynamically located each with selenium.

```
img_src = button_soup.find('img')['src']
path_location = "//img[contains(@src,'{}')]".format(img_src)
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, path_location).click()
```